# Jenkins/Maven Incremental Build troubles

Tags: java, maven, svn, jenkins

I've been tasked with picking up all the maven/jenkins related projects. Currently whenever a SCM change comes through in jenkins (svn driven), the altered file is rebuilt and everything that depends on it builds and this effect cascades. While this is in a sense good, it is not the preferred behavior. What is currently desired is that the altered file is built and everything immediately dependent builds without it cascading forward unless the second file is now different. The only solution(?) I can still think of is that Jenkins/Maven is not actually aware of the relationship between projects and isn't doing the limited cascade because it doesn't no where to trigger a build.

Within Jenkins, disabling the "Build whenever a snapshot dependency is built" and instead using in the advanced build options using "incremental build". Polling scm is also enabled. 
Jenkins no longer has on the project page any explicit knowledge of up/downstream projects.

When a SCM change comes through, there is no cascade effect to the immediately dependent modules.
Jenkins was not taking care of the incremental step so a incremental-build-plugin was used, no different behavior happened.

In a sandbox environment meant to simulate what our actual project is trying to accomplish.

*Sandbox setup*

```
 |Trunk
 --|Project_C
 | -Pom.xml
 | -src
 --|Project_B
 | -pom.xml
 | -src
 --|Project_A
 | -pom.xml
 | -src
```

Project A depends on Project B.
Project B depends on Project C.

When a change is made (+ SCM'd) in the src code of Project C that would effect the behavior of Project B Jenkins only rebuilds Project_C.

pom.xml for Project C

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>project</groupId>
    <artifactId>c</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>c</name>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
          <groupId>org.jvnet.maven.incrementalbuild</groupId>
              <artifactId>incremental-build-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>incremental-build</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
              </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

pom.xml for Project B

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>project</groupId>
    <artifactId>b</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>b</name>
    <build>
        <plugins>
      <plugin>
              <groupId>org.jvnet.maven.incrementalbuild</groupId>
              <artifactId>incremental-build-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>1.3</version>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>incremental-build</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
              </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>project</groupId>
            <artifactId>c</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Side Note: Does anyone greatly understand the interaction between the "incremental build" option with the "build whenever a snapshot dependency is built" option?

Answer (score 0):

It is not jenkins plugin, it is underlying maven which is not able to detect this change, [I have an open request for it already See: MNG-5523](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5523)

Comment: So what exactly does the Incremental build option do? For me it seems to do well.. nothing.

Comment: Super late, but you guys are talking about different things. The other answer below (probably spam) is about "incremental-build-plugin" which is something entirely different as well.